# Turkish visa invitation letter

Tags: tourist-visas, turkey, invitation-letters, german-residents

I am thinking of applying for a tourist visa for Turkey. I am a citizen of a country that do not qualify for the Turkish e-visa and I live in Germany (with a blue card residence permit). After filling out their online form, a list of the required documents was given according to my information input. There are some parts that are a bit confusing for me, including:

**Visa Conditions**

- If you have an invitation letter from person(s) in Turkey, before submitting your invitation to the Turkish consulate, make sure that the letter includes the inviting person's TR, etc.

*This part suggests that the letter is optional.*

**Visa Requirements**

- Documents attesting to the income status of the applicant and inviting person
- Hotel booking or invitation
  etc...

**Question**: Do I need a letter from a Turkish citizen or is it something extra to support my application?

PS: I tried contacting them but had no luck. I am not visiting any particular person.

Comment: It depends on the reason. A invitation from a random people that do no match with your intention in Turkey is worthless.  If you go to visit them, than it is ok (especially if your are living with them so no hotel). But usually for tourism you do not need invitation letter (but ev. from hotel or tour operators).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Ok, I am not visiting anyone. So I assume I don't need a letter from a person.

Comment: Right. Hotel and travel program are enough. Take care that this requires to show some more funds (but this is always good).

Comment: You are a citizen of which country exactly?

Comment: @Giorgio Yes, I am certain.

Comment: Are you travelling with a German travel document or German passport.

Answer (score 3):

It's conditional, among [General Information About Turkish Visas](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/general-information-about-turkish-visas.en.mfa), only necessary when a person or company in Turkey has extended an invitation (*added emphasis mine*).

> **Tourist Visa**
>
> ***If*** an invitation letter is submitted for a Touristic Visa application, it must include the inviting person's TR Identity Number, clear identity, the list of invitees, permanent address, contact number, length and purpose of stay and the affinity with the applicant must be stated in the letter. ***If*** the inviting side is an organization or a company, tax registration certificate of the organization will be required. In the invitation letter it is also required for the inviting person/authority to pledge for covering victuals and accommodation expenses and for taking their own responsibility. The applicant is required to have sufficient and/or regular remunerations.

Comment: I get that. But the visa requirement suggest something else: Documents attesting to the income status of the applicant AND inviting person